# How to read .vma files?

Tags: linux, files, memory

I am trying to read a ***.vma*** file but no luck finding an application to do it on Linux.. I tried to google it but it didn't work out..

The file was produced by *Volatility* on ***Ubuntu Linux 12.04*** using `linux_dump_map` command for a specific process !

Any ideas how to read the content of it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on Github : https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility

You could try :

```
$linux_yarascan
```

or :

```
$linux_volshell
```

which should open a shell in the linux memory image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer ..!!! I knew it was a plugin I just didn't know which one it was.. I am new into forensics ! Thanks again :-)